# how to stop a while loop in python-telegram from client side

Tags: python, while-loop, telegram, python-telegram-bot

How can I stop a while loop inside a function which is passed as a parameter for a telegram bot `CommandHandler`, using a command or text from the client side?

I have this bot:

```
from telegram import *
from datetime import datetime
import time
from telegram.ext import *
import ast #ignore this. i'll use it later

RUN_FUNC = True
def func_starter(update: Update, context):
    update.effective_chat.send_message('Function innitiated.')
    counter = 0
    RUN_FUNC = True
    while RUN_FUNC:
        print(f'function running for {counter} seconds.')
        counter += 1
        time.sleep(1)


def func_stopper(update: Update, context):
    update.effective_chat.send_message('function stopped')
    RUN_FUNC = False


def main():
    updater = Updater('*********:***********************************', use_context=True)
    dp = updater.dispatcher
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("stop", func_stopper))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", func_starter))

    updater.start_polling(0)
    updater.idle()

main()
```

So the bot gets the /start command from the client and it starts the `func_starter` function which has conditional while loop in it. But because the program never makes it past the while loop, any other command / text from the client, never gets registered by the python code therefore the loop goes on forever. I want to be able to stop the `func_starter` function, using a command from the client side.
I even made a global variable but obviously to no avail lol. It is logical I think that the program never makes it past the while loop, so is there any way to listen for new commands while in the loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see two options:

1. pass `run_async=True` to `CommandHandler("start", …)`, which will make `func_starter` run in its own thread.
2. Instead of using a while loop inside callbacks, use [JobQueue](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Extensions-%E2%80%93-JobQueue) to schedule the next steps

Comment: First option worked like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: Sweet. Keep in mind that this will still block one of the `worker` threads as long as the loop is running ;)